# CoffeeScript Code UnitTest AngularJS - Jasmine - Karma

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test to my Controllers and services of my Ionic project written with CoffeeScript. I chose to use Karma and Jasmine. The problem is it doesn't interpreter coffeeScript. That's why I used this plugin karma-coffee-preprocessor so that it will be possible. I don't know if I am doing it right.

I installed the plugin with the command ; 
`npm install --save-dev karma-coffee-preprocessor`
I then configured my test config file as follows:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        '../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../src/scripts/**/*.coffee',
        'unit-tests/**/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        '../src/scripts/**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
    },

    coffeePreprocessor: {
      options: {
        bare: true,
        sourceMap: false
      },
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.coffee$/, '.js')
      }
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

But when I try to start my test I have this error :

```
 Can not load "coffee", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
      ^

Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)
    at error (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:22:12)
    at Object.parent.get (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9:13)
    at get (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:54:19)
    at /opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:138:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server._start (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:137:21)
    at invoke (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.start (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:102:18)
    at Object.exports.run (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/cli.js:243:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
```

Can anyone help me ?
I having trouble making these unit tests, and I don't know if I am doing things the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to install jasmine framework via npm and add it to the frameworks collection in karma config file:

```
$ npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
```

then add:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine']
```

to karma config file.